# Regex help match everything after given word which ends with some file extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to match every string which contains "assets" and has a given extension ending - lets say png, jpeg, json.

Those are the cases I could think of and currently, the regex I was able to come with is handling only the first three.

Those are the strings I test against -

```
./assets/example.js
./assets/recursive-directory/example/exampleTwo.json
../assets/recursive-directory/example/exampleThree.json
../../../assets/recursive-directory/example/exampleThree.json
C:\Users\user1\project\assets\game-assets\translates.json
```

And here is my current regex -

```
\.*\/assets\/.*\.(png|jpe?g|gif|json|js)$
```

Comment: A slash only matches a slash, not a backslash (and does not need to be escaped in most regex dialects); try `[\/]` instead of `\/`.

Comment: The optional literal dots before `/assets/` are not contributing anything here; they are not preventing a string with something else than a dot from matching.

Comment: @tripleee `.*[\/]assets\/.*\.(png|jpe?g|gif|json|js)$` like that its better and I am matching everything except the final string - `C:\Users\user1\project\assets\game-assets\translates.json`

Comment: Because you forgot to change the second slash. The leading `.*` remains superfluous in most regex applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match either slashes or backslashes, you need to say so.

```
[\\/]assets[\\/].*\.(png|jpe?g|gif|js(on)?)$
```

The leading `\.*` wasn't contributing anything useful, so I took it out.

In Javascript, you'll need to backslash-escape the literal backslash, even in a character class.

Comment: Here is a link to regex101 where I tried it and I feel like this does not cover the last case. 

For host language, It will be used in JS

https://regex101.com/r/WHY9Xh/1

Comment: Thanks for finally revealing which regex dialect you are using. In Javascript, try `[\\/]`

Comment: I am not well educated about the regex world and that it had different dialects.. thanks for the help and I guess it's time for me to start learning it step by step. :)_